# Exporting QGIS Layout to Webmap

Tags: qgis, html

I am testing setting up QGIS dashboards. According to https://www.linkedin.com/advice/0/what-some-tips-tricks-create-interactive-qgis-dashboards you can export a QGIS dashboard as html via the layout using Layout > Export as Web Map. I don't see this option in the Layout export tools, in QGIS 3.30 (the latest). Am I missing something?

Comment: I think that might be a an outdated article perhaps? (Quantum GIS is a rather old way of referring to the software). Or they have a custom plugin that they forgot to write about... You can try using the qgis2web plugin to achieve a similar export of your spatial data and symbology to an HTML map using OpenLayers, Leaflet or Mapbox GL JS.

Comment: Also according to the statement at the top of the article, it is an "AI powered collaborative article". It seems to include some hallucinations. I think we will be seeing more of this type of AI generated articles/ blogs etc.

Comment: I saw that also. Interesting.